# Google docs and curl

Tags: php, curl, google-docs

I've created a curl script which looks for a google document, I want to validate that the document exists I've tried to do this by looking for anything other than a response code of 200 but when I get 500 from google it injects html into my page see picture.

```
  $url = 'https://docs.google.com/document/d/MU8-F3dtCYcv6bprrt0ic/pub';
  $ch  = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
  if (curl_errno($ch) > 0) {
      echo 'curl failed';
  }
  elseif ($curl_info['http_code'] != 200) {
      echo 'page does not exist';
  }
```

[image: Google docs internal 500 error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

that way you can set a variable to the result of the curl_exec and do something depending on what you get back.

```
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

i.e only output the result if the request was successful.

```
if ($curl_info['http_code'] == 200) echo $result;
```